# Mac で Spresense SDK のセットアップ時、Command not found と表示されてしまう

Tags: macos, spresense

macOS向けセットアップの3番で `bash install-tools.sh` を実行すると "command not found" が表示され進みません。どうしたらいいでしょうか？

環境はMacBook Air、macOSはMojaveで行っています。

```
$ curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sonydevworld/spresense/install-tools.sh > install-tools.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    21  100    21    0     0      9      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--     9
```

この後

```
$ bash install-tools.sh
install-tools.sh: line 1: 400:: command not found
```

となります。

ルートの下にinstall-tools.shが作られており中身が "400: Invalid request" となっています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ここから引用
https://qiita.com/nara256/items/faa639e9ac8083977a66

チュートリアルに書かれているURLが間違っているみたいです。正しくは↓

```
$ curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sonydevworld/spresense/master/install-tools.sh > install-tools.sh
$ bash install-tools.sh
```

Comment: チュートリアルも既に訂正されてました。https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-nuttx/set-up-the-nuttx-environment#_macos向けセットアップ

Answer (score 1):

私のMacではセットアップがすんなりいきましたよ。
ログ：

```
$ bash install-tools.sh
== Install base command line tools
== Install additional tools
=== Download nuttx-tools.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  732k  100  732k    0     0   119k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--  153k
=== tar xvzf nuttx-tools.tar.gz --strip-components=1 -C nuttx-tools  .................
=== ./configure --prefix=/Users/taro/spresenseenv/usr --disable-shared --disable-nconf  ...............
=== make install  ................
=== make install PREFIX=/Users/taro/spresenseenv  .
== Install cross toolchain
=== Download gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update-mac.tar.bz2
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   243  100   243    0     0     16      0  0:00:15  0:00:14  0:00:01    66
100 99.6M  100 99.6M    0     0   250k      0  0:06:46  0:06:46 --:--:--  281k
=== tar vjxf gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update-mac.tar.bz2 --strip-components=1 -C /Users/taro/spresenseenv/usr  ..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
=== Download gnu-mcu-eclipse-openocd-0.10.0-12-20190422-2015-macos.tgz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   647    0   647    0     0    973      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   972
100 2736k  100 2736k    0     0   135k      0  0:00:20  0:00:20 --:--:--  369k
=== Download gnu-mcu-eclipse-openocd-0.10.0-12-20190422-2015-macos.tgz.sha
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   651    0   651    0     0   1952      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1949
100   124  100   124    0     0     14      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--    31
gnu-mcu-eclipse-openocd-0.10.0-12-20190422-2015-macos.tgz: OK
=== tar vzxf gnu-mcu-eclipse-openocd-0.10.0-12-20190422-2015-macos.tgz --strip-components=3 -C /Users/taro/spresenseenv/usr  ...................................................................................
Installation is done.
```

何処でエラーが起きているのかが分からないので、 `bash install-tools.sh` を実行したときのログを張った方がもう少し良いアドバイスがもらえるかもしれません。

あとmacOSの情報もあるとさらに良いと思います。
参考までに私のMacは2015年版のMac miniでOSはmacOS High Sierraです。